# Tomcat 8 ignores CORS filters (web.xml, in-code, etc)

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, cors

for some weird reason, Tomcat 8 (on a w2k12 server) is ignoring my CORS filter settings on tomcat8/conf/web.xml which are as follows, according to the Apache Tomcat 8 docs:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It does work with GET requests, but when I try to do a POST, i get the 403 Forbidden error saying:

```
Origin http://webapp.mycompany.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Where http://webapp.mycompany.com is my company's hosting provider with standard features you get with a shared hosting with cpanel, my front-end is there and it send the requests to another domain where I have the Tomcat 8 Server installed and the webapp WAR which is a Jersey-based REST Api.

Now, according to the defaults in Apache's official documents, that configuration I'm using is the minimum required for it to work.

I tried then moving the filters to the application's web.xml instead, no luck, tried adding more configurations like methods allowed, tried adding the headers in the responses directly like this:

```
Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
        .entity(relaciona)
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")
        .build();
```

Didn't work.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, and just to confirm, tried the following:

- Tried setting the configuration in both the server and the webapp web.xml files individually, no luck
- Tried adding the headers to each response in the Jersey REST Api, no luck
- The requests to the API are done with an HTML5 frontend with bootstrap and jQuery, tried adding the crossDomain:true to the ajax requests, no difference.
- Added the origin domain to the xml in both web and server web.xml files (tested individually) and neither worked

Thanks!

Comment: hi Adrian E. Labastida Cañizares, have you @Option function implemented in order to perform POST in your response. Can you retrieve the response network detailed info (status code, message....) in order to help you.

Comment: The response code I get when doing POST is 403 Forbidden and the message is there too the Origin http://webapp.mycompany.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, regarding the @Option function, where should I try that? Thanks

Comment: have your given a try to @Option (response below) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you are querying a POST with crossdomain, you need to define @OPTION for @POST /@PUT / @DELETE queries.

Have you defined @Option class in order to define your @Post?

here is an example on how to do so:

```
@OPTIONS
@Compress
@Path("/mypost")
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response mypost_opts() {
    return Response.ok().build();
}



@POST
@Compress
@Path("/mypost")
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response mypost() {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: I didn't have that @OPTIONS annotation and code for it, I'll give it a try, thanks!